# Get items from sharepoint list by Title field with ignore care using Caml or SPQuery

Tags: sharepoint, moss, caml, spquery, ignore-case

I want to get data from SharePoint List using CAML and filtered by Title with ignore case like

```
<Query>
   <Where>
      <Eq>
         <FieldRef Name='Title' />
         <Value Type='Text'>Car</Value>
      </Eq>
   </Where>
</Query>
```

But with ignore case so if i have an item with title: `car` the caml should return it
how can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found out it's ignoring case by default.

Comment: and I think it's depending on the sql collation